# Can the Lightweight Testing Automation Framework (LTAF) be used in Continuous Integration?

Tags: continuous-integration

I'm interested in using the [Lightweight Testing Automation Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Wiki/View.aspx?title=ASP.NET%20QA&referringTitle=Home) (LTAF) to create integration tests for my web application.  However, I need it to be run on the build server.  Does anyone know if this can set up to do this?

There does not seem to be a whole lot of information on the web on this right now :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a blog post ([Lightweight Test Automation Framework – Automated Build Support](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2009/06/lightweight-test-automation-framework.html)) that describes how to implement the runner as a console application, it can then be integrated into a build server fairly simply by redirecting the build output and setting the return code appropriately.

The author posted the code used in the article, you can download it from [here](http://sites.google.com/site/jacopretoriusbloghost/Home/Blog.LTAF.TestRunner.rar?attredirects=0).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with LTAF, but found this nice article:

[First steps with Lightweight Test Automation Framework](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/03/27/first-steps-with-lightweight-test-automation-framework/)

Quoting the author (Steve Sanderson, from the comments):

> Lightweight Test Automation Framework
>   can be invoked with query string
>   parameters (to specify which tests to
>   run) and can emit a log of the results
>   to a text file, so it would be
>   possible to integrate it. However,
>   this is certainly not as easy as using
>   Selenium RC which as you say works
>   through a traditional test runner.